# WooCommerce shop loop random array function not same values after each other

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I‘m using this array function to output random input values in the WooCommerce shop loop. I try now to have it like this, that the same input are not selected after each other.

**Example**:
I have 4 different input values in the array. Now if [0] is randomly selected then for the second catch its not possible to select [0] again. Only [1], [2] and [4] would be possible. If [2] is selected for the second input then for the third select only the values [0], [1] and [3] should be selected.

In general: Not select the same array value for input after each other. But it should be possible that some inpute are selected more than once… but not after each other…

Is something somehow possible?

```
// Adding custom content block to shop loop row

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'add_custom_content_to_shop_loop_row' );
function add_custom_content_to_shop_loop_row() {

    // Variables
    global $wp_query;
    
    // Custom array input options
    $input = array("<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-001.svg'>", "<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-002.svg'>", "<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-003.svg'>" );

    // Column count
    $columns = esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) );
    
    // Add content every X product
    if ( (  $wp_query->current_post % 7 ) ==  0 && $wp_query->current_post !=  0 ) {
        
    // output random array custom content
        $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);

        echo $input[$rand_keys] . "\n";
    }

}
```

I tried to use a method from here https://ofstack.com/PHP/37611/summary-of-5-methods-of-generating-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-php.html but it does not work at all.

Comment: `if ( (  $wp_query->current_post % 7 ) ==  0 && $wp_query->current_post !=  0 ) {
        
  // output random array custom content
  do{
   $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1); // Change the banner if previously set the same one.
  }while($rand_keys === $_COOKIE['previous_banner']);
  
        echo $input[$rand_keys] . "\n";
  setcookie('previous_banner', $rand_keys); // Store the current bnner
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, you can store the value temporarily via a cookie, sessions, transients, meta data.. but personally I would go for a global variable so that no database requests are needed.

So you get:

```php
function random_result() {
    // Input
    $input = array( '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-001.svg">', '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-002.svg">', '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/banner-003.svg">' );

    // NOT isset (result) OR NOT isset (counter)
    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['result'] ) || ! isset( $GLOBALS['counter'] ) ) {
        // Shuffle an array
        shuffle( $input );

        // Globals
        $GLOBALS['result'] = $input;
        $GLOBALS['counter'] = 0;
    } else {
        // Plus 1
        $GLOBALS['counter'] += 1;
    }

    // Store
    $counter = $GLOBALS['counter'];

    // Limit is reached, reset
    if ( $counter == ( count( $input ) - 1 ) ) {
        unset( $GLOBALS['counter'] );
    }

    return $GLOBALS['result'][$counter];
}

function action_woocommerce_shop_loop() {
    // Variables
    global $wp_query;
    
    // Add content every X product
    if ( (  $wp_query->current_post % 7 ) ==  0 && $wp_query->current_post !=  0 ) {
        // Call function, display result
        echo random_result();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop' );
```

Comment: work perfectly! Thanks. Is such a solition maybe also a problem in terms of perfomance?

Comment: @Nik7 I believe that of all possible solutions this one is the least burdensome in terms of perfomance   since this is most similar to using a local variable

Answer (score 1):

You would have to remember the previously chosen value somehow, and then ignore that key when calling the function the next time.

```
// Get the latest key - I've saved this as a transient, but you can use another method.
$previous = get_transient( 'previous_content_index' );
if ( $previous !== false ) { // Check explicitly for false, as the previous key may be "0".
    // Array diff will temporarily remove the previous index.
    $input = array_diff_key( $input, array( $previous => '' ) );
}
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
// Remember this key for next time.
set_transient( 'previous_content_index', $rand_keys, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
```